# unable to connect to Azure SQL database from Jsp

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm new to MS Azure and I'm trying to connect to the SQL database in Azure using the following code.
When i publish this same code and try to access it in Azure I'm getting 404 error.
Also, if I this same code to connect it from local server, connection gets refused.
I have attached error along with this question.
Can anyone help me?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>DB connection</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Azure DB connection</h1>
<%

    final String DB_URL =
"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://pkynvzyf2a.database.windows.net/nj-javapocdb";

   //  Database credentials
   final String USER = "Username"; 
    final String PASS = "Password";

   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver

     Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "SELECT StudentID, FirstName, LastName FROM
        StudentDetails";


      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
      while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name

         Integer id  = rs.getInt("StudentID");
         String last = rs.getString("LastName");
         String first = rs.getString("FirstName");

         //Display values
         System.out.print("ID: " + id);
         System.out.print(", First: " + first);
         System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
      }
      //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");

   %>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Error in local:

```
Connecting to database...
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused:
connect
Goodbye!
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:436)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:141)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service
(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke
(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke
(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke
(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke
(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke
(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke
(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke
(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service
(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process
(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun
(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run
(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run
(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3
(SharedSocket.java:288)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:251)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:331)
... 31 more
```

[error in azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS7KR.png)

Answer (score 0):

All services in Azure are locked down and secure by default. Therefore, you need to allow access to the SQL Azure instance.

- If you are running from your local machine, then you external IP address most be whitelisted.
- If you are using Azure Websites/App Services you need to allow them to access also.

See how-to [configure firewall settings for an Azure SQL database instance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/).

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right port? Use port 1433

The portal recommends the following connection string to my database:

jdbc:sqlserver://cvqoa5mk72.database.windows.net:1433;database=mydatabase;user=user@cvqoa5mk72;password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;

Comment: What was the issue? Out of curiosity.